# WebScraping / Identical sites not working?

Tags: web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i would like to scrape the header-element from these both links -
For me this 2 sites look absolute identical - pics see below

Why is only the scraping for the second link working and not for the first?

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# not working
link = "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bingo-story-live-bingo-games/id1179108009?uo=4"
page = requests.get (link)
time.sleep (1)
soup = BeautifulSoup (page.content, "html.parser")
erg = soup.find("header")
print(f"First Link: {erg}")

# working
link = "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/jackpot-boom-casino-slots/id1554995201?uo=4"
page = requests.get (link)
time.sleep (1)
soup = BeautifulSoup (page.content, "html.parser")
erg = soup.find("header")
print(f"Second Link: {len(erg)}")
```

Working:
[image]

Not Working:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page is sometimes loaded by JavaScript, so `request` *won't* support it.

You can use a `while` loop to check if `header` appears in the `soup` and then `break`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36"
}
link = "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bingo-story-live-bingo-games/id1179108009?uo=4"

while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "html.parser")
    header = soup.find("header")
    if header:
        break

print(header)
```

Comment: It's not 100% - sometimes the server returns Js-only page. You need to repeat it until the server sends correct version.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Interesting, since I tested it with my browser a few times with disabling JS. You can post an answer instead of me. I'll upvote

Comment: It's ok - just mention it in your answer for OP. +1 :)

Comment: @AndrejKesely How did you notice that sometimes the page is _sometimes_ loaded dynamically? are you already familiar with this website? Also, I always like your solutions, if you still want to post one, I would like to see your approach

Comment: The first thing I did is that I set-up `User-Agent`...but when I had answer already written and tried to copy the output, I run once more the script and it failed :/ So no magic :)

Comment: @AndrejKesely I updated my answer to check for a response. It seems that the `user-agent` isn't needed at all.

Comment: Would it help to read this with selenium instand of normal request or is there no chance to scrape this? And why is it only working all the time with the first page?

Comment: It worked for around 200 rows - and then suddenly this lines only gave me an empty return back:      page = requests.get (link)     soup = BeautifulSoup (page.content, "html.parser")

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get whatever fields you wish to grab from those links. curently it fetches the title. You can modify `res.json()['data'][0]['attributes']['name']` to grab any field of your interest. Mkae sure to put the urls within this list `urls_to_scrape`.

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import unquote

urls_to_scrape = {
    'https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bingo-story-live-bingo-games/id1179108009?uo=4',
    'https://apps.apple.com/us/app/jackpot-boom-casino-slots/id1554995201?uo=4'
}

base_url = 'https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bingo-story-live-bingo-games/id1179108009?uo=4'
link = 'https://amp-api.apps.apple.com/v1/catalog/US/apps/{}'

params = {
    'platform': 'web',
    'additionalPlatforms': 'appletv,ipad,iphone,mac',
    'extend': 'customPromotionalText,customScreenshotsByType,description,developerInfo,distributionKind,editorialVideo,fileSizeByDevice,messagesScreenshots,privacy,privacyPolicyText,privacyPolicyUrl,requirementsByDeviceFamily,supportURLForLanguage,versionHistory,websiteUrl',
    'include': 'genres,developer,reviews,merchandised-in-apps,customers-also-bought-apps,developer-other-apps,app-bundles,top-in-apps,related-editorial-items',
    'l': 'en-us',
    'limit[merchandised-in-apps]': '20',
    'omit[resource]': 'autos',
    'sparseLimit[apps:related-editorial-items]': '5'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(base_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    token_raw = soup.select_one("[name='web-experience-app/config/environment']").get("content")
    token = json.loads(unquote(token_raw))['MEDIA_API']['token']
    s.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
    s.headers['Referer'] = 'https://apps.apple.com/'
    s.headers['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {token}'

    for url in urls_to_scrape:
        id_ = url.split("/")[-1].strip("id").split("?")[0]
        res = s.get(link.format(id_),params=params)
        title = res.json()['data'][0]['attributes']['name']
        print(title)
```